# No refresh token while authorizing Device Access

Tags: nest-device-access

I am able to successfully authorize a user through Partner Connections Manager, but when I request tokens from `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` using my authorization code, I do not receive a `refresh_token` in the response, only an `access_token` is present:

```
{
  access_token: 'my-access-token',
  expires_in: 3599,
  scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sdm.service',
  token_type: 'Bearer'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to specify `access_type=offline` in your Partner Connections Manager (PCM) URL. Omitting it assumes `access_type=online`, which does not provide a refresh token.

For example, the PCM URL should look something like this, where `access_type=offline`:

```
https://nestservices.google.com/partnerconnections/project-id/auth?
  redirect_uri=my-redirect-uri&
  access_type=offline&
  prompt=consent&
  client_id=my-client-id&
  response_type=code&
  scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sdm.service
```

Then, the subsequent token response from `https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` should have what you expect:

```
{
  "access_token": "my-access-token",
  "expires_in": 3599,
  "refresh_token": "my-refresh-token",
  "scope": "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/sdm.service",
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

For more information, see [Authorize an Account](https://developers.google.com/nest/device-access/authorize) on the Device Access site.